# How many different combinations are possible

Tags: permutations

Say there are 4 stations for ice cream toppings.

```
station1: 3 choices
station2: 2 choices
station3: 2 choices
station4: 3 choices
```

How many different combinations toppings can I get assuming I pick 1 topping from each station?

Would it be 3 * 2 * 2 * 3 = 36

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming the combinations don't need to be distinct (or no 2 stations serve the same choice).

Personally, I prefer distinct ice cream toppings on my ice cream.

Comment: All 10 choices are distinct and I'm only looking for distinct combinations, should have specified in problem.